# Usage of the "Random" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [random](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/random) tag seems to attract taggers of all kinds, from using random number generators (which I think is the right usage) to people complaining about their computers "randomly" shutting down.

How should this tag be used?

Comment: @random will handle it in... random fashion

Comment: If ever there was a tag that deserved ambiguity...

Comment: +1 because digitxp _seeded_ the question with an opinion regarding correct usage -- random number generation.

Comment: @Randolf: [tag:random-number-generator] is more clear for that purpose

Comment: @Tom Wijsman:  I just checked the "random" tag and it seems that there are no questions tagged to it; perhaps it's not even needed.

Comment: @Randolf: That's because Random and I already worked through that tag. I improved some titles/content and added other more specific tags along the way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a meta tag at best and now that it's been wiped away, there isn't much to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Random should only be for questions or discussions about randomness and or random number generators , not random events that are happening.